# Using a couple if, and else's in 1 line

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to use

```
"HCA_Status": 5 if CS.hcaSwitch else 7 if (lkas_enabled and apply_steer != 0) else 3,
```

in my code,
I want "HCA_Status" to be 5 if hcaSwitch is True (it is a boolian controlled else where) otherwise be 7, if lkas_enabled is true and apply steer is not zero, if apply steer does not equal zero and lkas_enabled is false I need HCA_Status to be 3

Does this make sense?
Sorry if this is confusing

Here is the complete code this would be in

```
    def create_pq_steering_control(packer, bus, apply_steer, idx, lkas_enabled, CS):
  values = {
    "HCA_Zaehler": idx,
    "LM_Offset": abs(apply_steer),
    "LM_OffSign": 1 if apply_steer < 0 else 0,
    "HCA_Status": 5 if CS.hcaSwitch else 7 if (lkas_enabled and apply_steer != 0) else 3,
    "Vib_Freq": 16,
  }
```

Does this make sense?

```
def create_pq_steering_control(packer, bus, apply_steer, idx, lkas_enabled, CS):
  values = {
    "HCA_Zaehler": idx,
    "LM_Offset": abs(apply_steer),
    "LM_OffSign": 1 if apply_steer < 0 else 0,
    "HCA_Status": (
      if CS.hcaSwitch:
        5
      elif lkas_enabled and apply_steer !=0:
        3
      else:
        7
    ),
    "Vib_Freq": 16,
  }
```

Comment: What doesn't make sense is why this must be on one line.

Comment: Definitely confusing.

Comment: Parentheses can help.

Comment: "Parentheses can help. – gilch" example please?

Comment: Lines aren't the same thing as expressions. You can write an expression over multiple lines. But why not factor it out into a function and then just call it?

Comment: just updated the post with where this is being used, im pretty sure i have to keep it on one line but im not certain on that

Comment: It's already wrapped in the {}, which mean you can use multiple lines.

Comment: @CurtisJenkins no. You *never* have to keep something on one line, or to be more precise, as a conditional expression. Just write it out using an `if... elif... else` statement.

Comment: Anyway, its hard to tell what you need, but it doesn't sound like you've exhausted the possibilities. What if apply steer == 0?

Comment: gilch, yeah i just cant wrap my head on how to break this out into multiple lines given i am giving a value to HCA_Status.. sorry lol, hmmmmmm

Comment: juanpa, if appy steer == 0 then we just send no steering but we want to keep the current HCA status. the lkas_enabled and apply steer !=0 is for when we do not want to control steering and we are not doing so, send the 3 status to indicate readyness to the power steering rack

Comment: I don't know what "we just send no steering means". It's hard to know what you are asking. If you had the logic, we can help you expresss it in Python. If you don't, are you asking us to help you come up with the logic? The whole one-line thing seems like a red herring

Comment: it doesnt matter if apply steer ==0 for how the code is currently setup

Comment: i am trying to make a bypass system for a timebomb found on a car's electronic power steering rack by flipping the hca modes. just as a poc

this bit trying to switch it in the value of HCA_Status just threw me for a whirl

Comment: updated post here

Comment: `"HCA_Status": 5 if CS.hcaSwitch elif (lkas_enabled and apply_steer !=0) 3 else 7,`

Answer (score 1):

An if-else ternary expression has three slots: `<then> if <condition> else <default>` You can put any expression in any of these slots, including another if-else. To disambiguate, use parentheses.

```
(a if b else c) if d else e  # "if b" expression in "if d"'s <then> slot.
a if b else (c if d else e)  # "if d" expression in "if b"'s <default> slot.
```

Also, an expression wrapped in brackets doesn't end until the closing bracket, even if you end the line, so

```
(
    a
    if
    b
    else
    c
)
```

is the same as

```
a if b else c
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible, it probably wouldn't be a good idea to do it style wise.

What you could do though, is have a function that checks the conditions and then returns a value.

```
def hca_status_function(CS, lkas_enabled, apply_steer):
    
    hca_status=None
    if CS.hcaSwitch:
        hca_status=5
    elif lkas_enabled and apply_steer != 0:
          hca_status=7
    else:
        hca_status=3
    return hca_status

values = {
    "HCA_Zaehler": idx,
    "LM_Offset": abs(apply_steer),
    "LM_OffSign": 1 if apply_steer < 0 else 0,
    "HCA_Status": hca_status_function(CS, lkas_enabled, apply_steer),
    "Vib_Freq": 16,
  }
```

Comment: i like the idea of this.. i can do that def above it

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this
`"HCA_Status": 5 if CS.hcaSwitch else 3 if (lkas_enabled and apply_steer !=0) else 7,` and it compiles/boots now.. will have to test in the AM if it works